# Did my dryer stop because the ground and neutral wires were connected?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dryer

The ground wire from the cord and the neutral wire from the dryer were wired together the dryer ran great for about 25 min then quit. Would that be a reason for it to stop?

Comment: Start at the beginning: 1 - **Where** are neutral and ground together? 2 - What model dryer? 3 - Upload picture of the existing plug/receptacle.

Comment: Its a Maytag.  I had a friend wire the cord to the dryer 4 prong same as the old dryer. He apparently put the green wire from cord to the nuetral wire on the dryer. And the other nuetral wire he put in the middle of the black and red. I had a load in the dryer i checked on it was doing great checked on it again and it had stopped. The clothes were near dry.  Its been wired correctly now and still not working will that cause the problem?

Comment: I think you've mistaken correlation for causation. Bonded grounds were a standard for decades until four-wire cords came on the scene. It's not likely to have caused your problem.

Comment: Do you have any idea what it could be?  This was the first time I used the dryer and was working good?

Comment: Did you check the breaker box to see if the breaker tripped?  
The question, as stated  is why it quit working, **should it be how to get it working?**. If the breaker has not tripped then read the **trouble shooting section of the manual**, is it new, does it have a digital display that gives error codes, If you can not figure out why it is not working, and the outlet has power,  then contact Maytag customer service. https://www.maytag.com/services/contact-us.html

Comment: Register your account so you can log in with an email/password or via Facebook or Google.  That will allow you to log in from different browsers and devices.  Then, hop on a phone and snap a flash photo of the wiring hookup, and [edit] to upload it.  Let's see what they did.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting ground and neutral together in an appliance is bad from a safety point of view and is likely to trip upstream GFCIs/RCDs if-any (though I don't think Americans normally have GFCIs on drier circuits) but it will not cause any problems for the appliance itself.

Comment: Well gfci’s are becoming required but upgrading an old 3 wire is not required and would not cause a problem with the dryers operation. The manufacturer instructions may say for them to be connected then it a requirement to do so. This was the standard for almost 100 years. (Neutral was ground including in sub panels)